# If, else if, both giving the same answer

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli

I've been having some problems with a bit of PHP running when a form is submitted.

I'm trying to have a variable be determined by which submit button is being pressed and grabbing the `$_POST['name']` to carry out some SQL select. There are currently two submit buttons in my form, reading YES and NO.

The problem I'm having is that I keep getting the same answer from my query, but when I test in my database it works just fine. It seems to be something in my `if`/`else` statement.

```
<?php

require_once ("/includes/session.php");
require_once ("/includes/db_connection.php");
require_once ("/includes/functions.php");
require_once ("/includes/validation_functions.php");

if ($_POST['answer1']) {
  $chosenAnswer = 1;
} else if ($_POST['answer2']) {
  $chosenAnswer = 2;
}

$query = "SELECT questionFlow.NxtQ FROM ";
$query .= "questionFlow WHERE area = '{$_SESSION['probArea']}' ";
$query .= "AND ANSid = '{$chosenAnswer}' AND Qid = '{$_SESSION['x']}'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  print_r($row["NxtQ"]);
}
?>



<form action="Assets/ajax/questions.php" id="ajax-questionset" method="post">

    <br />
    <br />
    <?php echo($howmany); ?>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div><?php echo($currentquestion); ?></div>
    <span>
        <button class="btn btn-hero" type="submit" name="answer1" value="1"/><?php echo($answer1); ?></button>
        <button class="btn btn-hero" type="submit" name="answer2" value="2"><?php echo($answer2); ?></button>
    </span>

</form>
```

As per Bug's suggestion below, I've added in the javascript and tested with an alert which is now giving me the right value, but it's messed up my ajax and it's now loading the php page rather than doing this 'blind' (for want of a better word)

Any suggestions?

```
function buttonB_clickHandler(event) {
document.getElementById('hiddenId').value = 2;
document.getElementById('ajax-questionset').submit();
```

}

Resolved this by taking out the javascript .submit and applying it to the buttons them self to read `type="submit"`.

**Thanks again for all your invaluable feedback guys, I love this site, great community!**

Comment: why the brackets `$chosenAnswer = ('x')` and did you start the session? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: Sidenote: This `if($_POST['answer1'])` could be changed to `if(!empty($_POST['answer1'] ))` which is better. etc.

Comment: Hi Fred, thanks for the quick reply!
Yea the session is started and I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: The brackets around the numbers are just a hangover from some previous code where it was something like this;

$chosenAnswer = ($_POST['answer2'][0]);

I've removed them since and still having the same issue. each time I'm getting back the answer of 2, which is the correct answer if it was answer1, but for answer2 the answer should be 3

Comment: you may need to add your HTML form

Comment: Added HTML form, hopefully this will help shed some light on it :)

Comment: The probem it's that you have the value in both buttons, so when you clic the second button it test the first if, and its true because the button 1 has a value. So it never gets to the else if. There is multiple answers to the problem, you can use javascript to change the value of a hidden field when you hit some button and use that value in the php if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read my comment and try something like this:

```
<input id="buttonA" type="button" value="do something" onclick="buttonA_clickHandler(event);"/>

function buttonA_clickHandler(event) {
    document.getElementById('hiddenId').value = whatever;
    document.getElementById('theForm').submit();
}
```

repeat the code for the other button changing the name of function and other code.

Comment: Thanks for the input Bugs! 

I've edited the question, adding your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding {} to the else statement and adding isset

```
    if(isset($_POST['answer1'])){
        $chosenAnswer = 1;
    } 
    else {
        if (isset($_POST['answer2'])){
        $chosenAnswer = 2;
        }
   }
```